# clean all partitions from hardisk and rebuild it again?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have installed Linux/Ubuntu to my PC but i cant understand how to combine my partitions `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` . Altough my `sda` looks unallocated, I cant make them one.

I have Ubuntu in USB and wanna install it to my PC from a clean harddisk, then  i need to divide it to 2 partitions again. One of them need to be ntfs, and the other partition is going to be where Linux installed. Please help me.!

Answer (score 1):

First, `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` are *disks,* not partitions. (In the Windows world, the term *disk* is sometimes applied to partitions, but the terms mean different things. A *disk* is a physical device, such as a disk that's built into a computer or an external disk. A partition is a subdivision of a disk as described in a [partition table,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_table) which is a simple data structure stored on a disk.) Partitions are normally numbered in Linux, as in `/dev/sda1` or `/dev/sdb5`.

Chances are either `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb` is your USB installation medium and the other one is the hard disk built into your computer, but it's impossible to say which is which based on the information you've presented. It could also be you've got two hard disks.

Second, you can't really combine two hard disks; they're physically separate devices. That said, there *are* ways to combine them *logically,* such as [RAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID) and [LVM.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) Depending on your situation, using one of these tools may be appropriate, but that's far from certain based on the information in your question.

Third, you say you want to divide your disk into two partitions, one of which should be NTFS. Why? If you intend to boot Linux alone on the computer, NTFS is a very poor choice for filesystem, for several reasons:

- **Poor performance** -- The NTFS-3g drivers used by Ubuntu are slow compared to the drivers for Linux-native filesystems like ext4fs, XFS, or Btrfs. Even FAT is faster in Linux (or was the last time I checked).
- **Repair impossibilities** -- You can't repair an NTFS volume from Linux. There is a tool called `ntfsfix`, but it just does some basic checks and then marks the volume as needing repair by Windows.
- **Lack of support for Unix/Linux features** -- Linux relies on Unix-style ownership, permissions, symbolic links, and some other filesystem features that are not provided by NTFS. (Actually, some of these *are* supported, but in ways that Linux can't use.) This prevents installing Linux to an NTFS volume. You can still store user data files on NTFS, but you may run into situations where you'll need these unsupported features even on a user-data volume.

Of course, if you want NTFS because you intend to dual-boot with Windows, that's fine. In case of dual-boot installations, though, it's easiest to install Windows first, mainly because the boot loader that Windows installs is much less flexible than the one that Ubuntu installs, and the last-installed boot loader normally becomes the default.

With all this in mind, you might want to re-state your question. What is your true goal? For instance, do you want to install Windows on a computer that already has Linux installed? Are you running out of space on one partition and so need to resize them? Something else?

Also, when you edit your question, please include the output of the following command:

```
sudo parted -l
```

Add four spaces to the start of each line of output. This will show us what your partition table(s) look like, which may be critical to answering your question.